# Hypothesis test for Multivariate Normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am trying to find a test statistics for the following hypothesis:

$$H_o: \mu=0 ;\hspace{4mm} H_a:\mu\neq0$$

when $\{X_i\}_{i}^{n}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$. I know I can perform a straight Hotellings $T^2$ to get a test statistic but I was wondering  if I know that $\mu$ points in the same direction of $\mu_o$ then if the following is an equivalent test. Since $\mu\in\text{C}(\mu_o)$, where $\text{C}(\mu_0)$ is the column space of $\mu_0$, if I can show $<\mu,\mu_o>=0$ then the hypothesis above is true, so I can just project $X_i$ onto $\mu_o$ and perform the following test

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}\mu_o^{t}\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\mu_0^{t}\Sigma\mu_0}}\sim N(0,1)$$.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: What is $\mu_0$?

Comment: $\mu_o$ is a vector that is Known and it is in the same direction of our distribution mean vector $\mu$